# feed popularity algorithm returning unknown column error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm fairly new to **SQL** so bear with me for the rather noob-like question.

Recently I've come up with an algorithm in order to rank posts on my website in order of popularity with decay. Where `L = likes, R = reposts, C = comments, P = plays, Tc = time created in hours and Tu = time updated in hours`, this is the formula:

> **((L + R) / 2) + 0.05C + 0.002P + 0.75) / (1 + Tc^1.8 - (Tc - Tu)^1.2)**

---

I've attempted to convert this into a basic **MySQL** query with the knowledge that I have and this is what I came up with:

```
SELECT
  Upload.upload_id,
  COUNT(L.like_id) AS c_likes,
  COUNT(R.repost_id) AS c_reposts,
  COUNT(C.comment_id) AS c_comments,
  (
    ((c_likes + c_reposts) / 2) + (0.05 * c_comments) + (0.002 * Upload.upload_plays) + 0.75
  ) / 
  (
    1 
    + POWER((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, Upload.upload_date) / 60), 1.8) 
    - POWER(0, 1.2) /* power is 0 for now as a placeholder */
  ) AS u_score
FROM
  uploads Upload
  LEFT JOIN likes L ON Upload.upload_id = L.like_target
  AND L.like_type = 0
  LEFT JOIN reposts R ON Upload.upload_id = R.track_id
  LEFT JOIN comments C ON Upload.upload_id = C.comment_track
GROUP BY
  Upload.upload_id
ORDER BY
  u_score DESC
LIMIT
  15
```

For some reason however, when I run this, I receive the error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'c_likes' in 'field list'
```

All help is appreciated, and if you think I could improve my code in any way, I'm more than happy to hear it :-)

Comment: `LIKE` is a reserved MySQL keyword, and you can't use it as an alias without escaping it in backticks (but...don't even try to do that).

Comment: (In your edited version)...I think you can't use the column alias name within the query itself. The alias is exposed to whatever code is calling the query, but not internally in another column definition. The columns are not aware of each other, or of each other's alias names.  I think you'll have to replace `c_likes + c_reposts` with `COUNT(L.like_id) + COUNT(R.repost_id)`, and `0.05 * c_comments` with `0.05 * COUNT(C.comment_id)`

Comment: @ADyson ah that makes sense, cheers I’ll give it a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't use a column alias name within the query itself. The alias is exposed to whatever code is calling the query, but not internally in another column definition. The columns are not aware of each other, or of each other's alias names.

I think you'll have to replace

```
(c_likes + c_reposts) / 2) + (0.05 * c_comments)
```

with

```
(COUNT(L.like_id) + COUNT(R.repost_id) / 2) + (0.05 * COUNT(C.comment_id))
```